# structuremap asp .net mvc registration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, structuremap, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using structuremap and Asp .Net MVC in a project. Currently I'm registering my dependency resolutions in the MVC layer for everything below it (service, data, etc.). However, I was wondering how I could do this by only registering what's directly below the MVC layer, namely, the Service layer. Basically my controllers have services injected into them and that's all I want my UI layer to know about. Within the service classes I have repositories injected and want those registered with structuremap in there... and so on. In other words, I want each layer to only be dependent (as much as possible) to the layer directly below it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A good approach is to use structuremap conventions combined with structuremap registries.  That will take care of most of your registration issues.  Structuremap can scan your bin and map dependencies that it finds in all dll's in your bin.

Look into the Scan method combined with a StructureMap Registry class:

```
Scan(x =>
{
    x.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(y =>
        y.FullName.StartsWith("JustLookAtTheseDlls"));

    // Use default conventions
    x.WithDefaultConventions().OnAddedPluginTypes(y =>
        y.HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()); 

    //Are there any registries?  If so, register them
    x.LookForRegistries();  
}
```

A registry looks something like this, and you can just drop one into each of your projects to register the items in each:

```
public class IocRegistry :
    StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Registry
{
    public IocRegistry()
    {
        For<IDocumentStore>().Singleton()
            .Use<RavenStore>();
    }
}
```

You root application should have the registry that contains the scan statement above.  Then initialize structuremap like so:

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.AddRegistry(
    new MyTopLevelRegistry()));
```

Where MyTopLevelRegistry looks like this:

```
public class MyTopLevelRegistry: Registry
{
    public MyTopLevelRegistry()
    {
        Scan(x =>
        {
            x.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(
                y => y.FullName
                .StartsWith("InsertYourNamespacePrefix"));

            x.WithDefaultConventions().OnAddedPluginTypes(
                y => y.HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped());

            x.LookForRegistries();
        });
    }
}
```

Keep in mind if you set it to "WithDefaultConventions" it will automatically map IMyClass to MyClass so you don't even have to specify that stuff in the registries.  You just have to register items that don't follow that convention.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the usage of a [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx) in a own library.

In the project i am working on we put the StructureMap registry in a library named xx.yy.IoC and we call the configuration code from Global.asax.

The MVC layer has only a link to the IoC library. The IoC Library has the dependencies to the other layers (Domain, Data, etc.)

As a tip: This article has changed our views about layering. [jeffrey palermo onion architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.

You have to register all the objects that will be resolved. Then in your controller you just expect ISomeService passed to constructor. Controller doesn't know that ISomeService has injected IRepositories for example.